# add_options_page not adding option to admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

So have the following code, which I am trying to create a custom plug-in for WordPress:

```
<?php

/*
    Plugin Name: Dump-It Scheduler
    Plugin URI: mycompany.com
    Description: my description
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Blaine 
    Author URI: myuri.net
    License: 

*/

function scheduler_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page('Dump-It Scheduling', 'Dump-It Schedule', 'Administrator', 'Dump-It_Master_Schedule'); 
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'scheduler_admin_actions'); 

?>
```

However, I don't see any addition link in the admin section of the app. I have activated the plugin, but I expect to see an option for this plugin. From what I understand I should see a link added to the admin panel.

I'll also add that I don't have any errors (I'm using a debugger plugin). Can't figure out what is going on here...

I am using WordPress 3.6.1 in case it matters.

What am I missing?

Comment: This should add a link to the Settings menu on the Dashboard. Do you not see it there, either? Are you sure you don't want [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) instead?

Comment: @acobster No, I didn't see it there in the setting menu. I was trying to get it to add the link to the settings. I think I'm going to do what you mentioned, and add to the menu page. This is my first plugin, so I'm taking it one step at a time. I did figure it out though...Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third parameter is a [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), and has to be `manage_options` or similar in your case. It even can be a role (although not recommended), but it has to be small caps and not `Administrator`.

You are missing the last parameter, which is the callback.

```
# http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page
add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
```

The order doesn't matter, this works:

```
function scheduler_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page(
        'Dump-It Scheduling', 
        'Dump-It Schedule', 
        'manage_options', 
        'Dump-It_Master_Schedule', 
        'my_callback'
    ); 
}
function my_callback()
{
    echo 'hello world';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'scheduler_admin_actions');
```

Comment: Isn't the callback an optional parameter, rather than a required one?

Comment: Well, but what do you want the menu for?

Comment: To display an admin page for the plug-in. I get that the callback is what can execute the call to display the data, I was just saying that not having the callback wouldn't prevent the menu from being displayed.

Comment: Yes, the menu displays without callback and takes to nowhere. But your error was **A**dministrator, instead of `administrator`, or `manage_options`.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had to move the `add_action` above the function like so:

```
  <?php

    /*
        Plugin Name: Dump-It Scheduler
        Plugin URI: mycompany.com
        Description: my description
        Version: 1.0
        Author: Blaine 
        Author URI: myuri.net
        License: 

    */
    //moved this call above the function definition
    add_action('admin_menu', 'scheduler_admin_actions'); 

    function scheduler_admin_actions()
    {
        add_options_page('Dump-It Scheduling', 'Dump-It Schedule', 'Administrator', 'Dump-It_Master_Schedule'); 
    }

?>
```